# Use ffmpeg To Batch Process M4A To M4A?

Tags: windows, audio, ffmpeg, batch

I've been using the code shown below to copy the AAC audio stream from 1 M4A container into a new M4A container.

```
ffmpeg -i "C:/Example/01 Example Song.m4a" -acodec copy "C:/Example2/01 Example Song.m4a"
```

I would like to do batch jobs instead of typing the details out for each file. I do NOT want to run a script. The code should do as a I have been, but will copy AAC streams from ALL the M4A files in the directory "C:/Example/" to an output of the same name in "C:/Example2/".

I'm using the 64bit static version of ffmpeg on **Windows** 8; this is my first time using ffmpeg so I would appreciate it if you'd disect your answer so that I can learn what each bit does.

Comment: You do realize that all [batch jobs](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/batchfil.htm) are a list of commands in a **script** to be executed by the shell?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? M4A to M4A copying just the codec - it's an audio stream only so what is ffmpeg actually doing to your files? From what I can see it's simply going to copy the file to your new folder...?

Comment: @Vinayak I guess we operate off differing definitions; to me a batch job is a task to be applied to multiple items. A script is a file that you save a commands to (such as those used in a batch job). To clarify my posting, I do not want to create a file (eg: a bat script) as I will be typing the ffmpeg code into the terminal by hand.

Comment: If you're going to type out the FFMPEG command, what exactly are you hoping to automate here?

Comment: Try this: `forfiles /C "cmd /c ffmpeg -i @file -acodec copy @file-out.mp3"`. That'll iterate through every file in the folder and send it to FFMPEG one by one.

Comment: @Vinayak How do I specify the input and output locations in that?

Comment: To set the path, use something like this: `forfiles /P "D:\Music\input" /C "cmd /c ffmpeg -i @file -acodec copy ..\output\\@file-out.mp3"`. This assumes that you already have a folder named `output` under ***D:\Music\***

Comment: @Vinayak How can I prevent "sourcefile.m4a" from being outputted as "sourcefile.m4a-out.m4a"?

Comment: I figured it out. Just put "@file" instead of "@file-out.m4a".

Comment: @RobinHood just curious- what is the purpose of this? I mean from one m4a to another "same" m4a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`FORFILES`](http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html) command for this. `FORFILES` only works in Windows Vista and later versions though.

```
forfiles /P "D:\Music\input" /C "cmd /c ffmpeg -i @file -acodec copy ..\output\\@file.mp3"
```

This is assuming you already have a folder named `output` under `D:\Music\`

Comment: You can specify a full output directory location too if desired. forfiles /P "C:\Example" /C "cmd /c ffmpeg -i @file -acodec copy C:\Example2\\@file"